# What's the syntax here?

Tags: java, swing

Im writing calculator in java Swing and having issue with syntax:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzSSi.jpg
cannot resolve symbol dotButtonText is fixible with initializing before dotButton method,but it still asking for ")"  ";"

```
  dotButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(TextFieldDisplay.getText().equals("")){
      TextFieldDisplay.setText("0");
    }
    else if (TextFieldDisplay.getText().contains(".")){
      dotButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
      (
              (String dotButtonText = TextFieldDisplay.getText()+dotButton.getText();
    TextFieldDisplay.setText(dotButtonText);

  }
});
```

I want to variable  dotButtonText to take default value of "" if not pressed,and ".0" if button is pressed

Comment: Is `";"expected  ")"expected  ")"expected after string` literally a line in your code? Because that won't compile for sure.

Comment: `else
      (
       ";"expected  ")"expected  ")"expected after string` is not valid Java code. What is your **actual** code, and what is the exact and complete error message?

Comment: Post your actual Java code. Then, after, not inside the code, post the exact and complete error message.

Comment: what is `dotButton` ? If that's part of the error message, that woul be useful to know more about that

Comment: dotButton is value of button in Swing form https://imgur.com/39by7Pq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else {
   //";"expected  ")"expected  ")"expected after string
   // (String dotButtonText = TextFieldDisplay.getText()+dotButton.getText();
   TextFieldDisplay.setText(dotButtonText);
}
```

You have added an extra `(`. Remove it and everything will work fine.

Comment: It fixes else if form but brakes other methods  https://imgur.com/8Sp4F0m

Answer (score 1):

1. You used `(` instead of a curly braces `{` for your else block.
2. You have an extra `(` at the beggining of your statement.

Remove those, and it will work fine:

```
else
{
    String dotButtonText = TextFieldDisplay.getText()+dotButton.getText();
    TextFieldDisplay.setText(dotButtonText);
}
```